# how to run this js inside the php?

Tags: javascript, php

ok so im trying to use a js script down the form inside the php but it seems that the script doesn't runs. Tried to run the script separately and it works like a charm

```
$list .= "<div id='single_product' >

<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
</br>
<h3>$pro_title</h3>
<p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪:מחיר</p>
<p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
</br>
<a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart'>הוסף לסל</button></a>

<form name='f1'> <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' />
<input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById('qty').value++;' value='+' />
<input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById('qty').value--;' value='-'/> 
</form>
</div>";
```

Comment: No you can't. Javascript is client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quote problem inside your scripts. You need to escape them:

```
javascript:document.getElementById(\"qty\").value++;
```

because the code you posted would output:

```
// Single quotes inside single quotes       v   v
onclick='javascript:document.getElementById('qty').value++;'
```

Fixed code:

```
$list .= "<div id='single_product' >
<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='100%' height='60%' /></a>
</br>
<h3>$pro_title</h3>
<p style='color:gray; text-decoration: line-through;'> $pro_fullprice ₪:מחיר</p>
<p style='color:#ff66ff; font-weight: bold; '> $pro_price ₪ :מחיר שלנו</p>
</br>
<a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button class='button_addCart'>הוסף לסל</button></a>

<form name='f1'> <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' />
<input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"qty\").value++;' value='+' />
<input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"qty\").value--;' value='-'/> 
</form>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Escape the single quotes used under JS**

```
<input type='button' name='add' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\'qty\').value++;' value='+' />
<input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\'qty\').value--;' value='-'/>
```